# Program Does not Contain static 'Main' method suitable for Entry point

Tags: c#

i learning C# class I have created simple its included this constructor and Destructor. finally i created method method its print First name and Last name . then inovoke this class  to main class using  instance  class. Called method name instance class object . showing Error  Program  Does not Contain static 'Main' method  suitable  for Entry point

```
using ClassSample;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassSample
{
    public class Student
    {
        string _firstname;
        string _lastname;

        public Student(string Firstname, string Lastname)
        {
            this._firstname = Firstname;
            this._lastname = Lastname;
        }

        public void printfulname()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FullName={0}", this._firstname + "" + this._lastname);

        }

        ~Student()
        {

        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void main()
    {

        Student S1 = new Student("Sri", "Priya");


        S1.printfulname();
    }
}
```

How to fix this issues ? Thanks in advance

Comment: *How to fix this issues ?* Decide which language you are using

Comment: Its C# console Application @ScaryWombat

Comment: Rename 'main' method to 'Main'. C# is a case sensitive language.

Comment: thank you sir @Nightwalker its Worked

Comment: @sripriya remember - c# is case-sensitive language. `main`, `MAIN` and `Main` are different names here

Answer (score 1):

Change your `public static void main()` to `public static void Main(string[] args)`

C# is a case sensitive language.